# Core plot: Library binary missing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-plot, ios-frameworks

I was following this link :

http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/pie-chart-drawing-in-iphone-using-core-plot-library.html

to plot values in Xcode.
But for me adding the daughter project CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj includes no libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a library binary to follow further instructions. I am using XCode 4.0.2..

[image: Screenshot in my Project]

This is how it should look like:

[image: Image from instruction page]

I already spend the whole day trying to include that framework :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the same settings, but they're in different places in Xcode 3 and Xcode 4. It looks like that tutorial was done with Xcode 3.

In Xcode 4, you get to the settings pane that you need by selecting your project on the left, clicking the target in the middle, and selecting the "Build Phases" tab on the right. Drag *libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a* from the Core Plot *Products* folder to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section on the right. Click the "+" under "Target Dependencies" and add *CorePlot-CocoaTouch*. The *.a* file still appears in red for me, but it compiles and links fine.
[image]

Comment: for me it was not working though. i checked every build setting and header search paths but it was still not recognizing the headerfiles.

Comment: in the end i just created a new sampleproject and changed this. its really a mess to implement this framework!